# Working with django template (Perform mathematical Calculations)

Tags: python, django

Am performing mathematical calculations in Django Template, How can I Round the Decimal Numbers before subtracting?
Here is my code:

```
# consider the following number returned from the view
cost1=17,643.08
cost2=66.16155

#when adding in django templates
{{ cost1|sub:cost2  }}

#results
17,577.08  #but it should be 17,576.91845
```

1. Why am getting 17,577.08 instead of 17,576.91845
2. I want to `floatformat:"2"` before subtracting them

I tried

```
{{ sub:cost2|floatformat:"2"|sub:cost2|floatformat:"2"  }}
```

expected result
17,643.08-66.16=17,576.92

am using **django-mathfilters==1.0.0**

Comment: IMO you have to define your own template tag for this purpose so that you can add round digits limits as per your requirement.

Comment: How you are getting cost1 in humanzed form as cost1=17,643.08  consist of comma and other doesn't?